# Ошибка при компиляции шейдера - Cannot convert from: "float" to: "highp int"

Tags: opengl, шейдеры, glsl

После создания переменных мой шейдер перестал компилироваться

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aUv;

out vec2 fUv;

uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    int x = 8 - floor(gl_InstanceID/9.0f + 1.0f)*9.0f - gl_InstanceID + 1;
    int y = floor(gl_InstanceID/9);
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * vec4(aPos.xy + vec2(x * 100 + 10 * x, y * 100 + 10 * y).xy, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    fUv = aUv;
}
```

Выводятся такие ошибки:

```
ERROR: 0:11: error(#160) Cannot convert from: "float" to: "highp int"
ERROR: 0:12: error(#160) Cannot convert from: "float" to: "highp int"
ERROR: error(#273) 2 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: С какой ошибкой не компилируется?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Vertex shader(s) were not successfully compiled before glLinkProgram() was called.  Link failed.

Comment: Это ошибка линковки, а нужна ошибка компиляции. `glGetShaderInfoLog`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `glGetShaderInfoLog` ничего не возвращает

Comment: А должен. Покажите код.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat изменил вопрос

Comment: `glGetShaderInfoLog` нужно вызывать на отдельном шейдере, а не на всей программе.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat понял, исправил вопрос

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо большое, добавил каст в переменные и теперь все работает)

Comment: Пожалуйста. :) По идее, с кастом и `floor` не нужен, ведь каст сам отбрасывает дробную часть.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat мне просто нужно округление вниз, а каст вроде округляет до ближайшего целого числа

Comment: А точно до ближайшего? Вот [тут](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#constructors) пишут, что отбрасывает дробную часть.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, и правда работает

Comment: Исправьте метку языка программирования